# A question about krb5p and sys on nfs shares

Tags: nfs

I made some shares with nfs
This is the /etc/exports file(I know the no_root_squash is dangerous but is only temporary, for testing)

```
/srv/nfs4              10.3.0.0/24(ro,no_subtree_check,fsid=0,sec=krb5p:sys) 192.168.0.0/24(ro,no_subtree_check,fsid=0,sec=krb5p:sys)
/srv/nfs4/kernels  10.3.0.0/24(rw,no_subtree_check,async,no_root_squash,nohide,sec=krb5p:sys) 192.168.0.0/24(rw,no_subtree_check,async,no_root_squash,nohide,sec=krb5p:sys)
```

If I mount the dir with sys option works all, posix acl are respected, and if I create a file as root, report permission as root(is this that I want).

```
mount -vvv -o sec=sys myserver:/kernels /mnt/
mount.nfs: timeout set for Tue Dec 28 07:18:41 2021
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'sec=sys,proto=tcp,retrans=2,retry=1,acl,ac,rsize=32768,wsize=32768,bsize=32768,port=2049,vers=4,addr=10.3.0.1,clientaddr=10.3.0.1'

cd /mnt
mkdir 44944
root@server:/mnt$ ls -lhd *
drwxr-xr-x 2 nobody nogroup 4,0K 28 dic 06.52 33/
drwxr-xr-x 2 root   root    4,0K 28 dic 07.10 449/
drwxr-xr-x 2 nobody nogroup 4,0K 28 dic 07.17 4494/
drwxr-xr-x 2 root   root    4,0K 28 dic 07.18 44944/
```

The problem is if I mount the dir with sec=krb5p, it force the mount as nobody:nogroup(sic!), i have tried giving the dir the 777 permission then enter as a kerberized user(i did kinit first) and I create a dir..it report the permission as nobody:nogroup.

```
mount -vvv -o sec=krb5p myserver:/kernels  /mnt/
mount.nfs: timeout set for Tue Dec 28 07:21:45 2021
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'sec=krb5p,proto=tcp,retrans=2,retry=1,acl,ac,rsize=32768,wsize=32768,bsize=32768,port=2049,vers=4,addr=10.3.0.1,clientaddr=10.3.0.1'

mkdir 449444
root@myserver:/mnt$ ls -lhd *
drwxr-xr-x 2 nobody nogroup 4,0K 28 dic 06.52 33/
drwxr-xr-x 2 root   root    4,0K 28 dic 07.10 449/
drwxr-xr-x 2 nobody nogroup 4,0K 28 dic 07.17 4494/
drwxr-xr-x 2 root   root    4,0K 28 dic 07.18 44944/
drwxr-xr-x 2 nobody nogroup 4,0K 28 dic 07.21 449444/
```

As you can se the dir is created as nobody nogroup(using chmod 777 otherwise give correctly permission denied)

What I have to check?
The server and client are both Debian 11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found.
I'm on a multinetworked server, which is connect with one interface to one network, and another one with the another network.
Before I use two "different" hostnames per network(the network A resolve my server as virt.domain.example and the network B resolve the server as router.domain.example)
I have done this change, using the same hostname(but different domain of course) per network, and now works perfectly after daemon restart.